# Conditional structure in Laravel blade template doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a css class with different colors in the laravel template how do I use the nested ternary operator on the laravel blade? I tried several ways but it didn't work,for example it uses "if statement" and does not work

```
<td 
  rowspan="{{count($awards)+1}}" 
  class="@if ($awards === 'DIAMOND')
             bg-white text-dark
          @elseif ($awards === 'RUBY')
             bg-danger text-white
          @elseif ($awards === 'EMERALD')
             bg-success text-white
          @else
             bg-white text-dark
          @endif">
             {{$award}}
</td>
```

Comment: `$awards` is an array or variable?

Comment: $awars is a key in a array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like :

```
<td rowspan="{{count($awards)+1}}" 
  class="

@foreach($awards as $award)
  @if ($award->color === 'DIAMOND')
     bg-white text-dark
  @elseif ($award->color === 'RUBY')
     bg-danger text-white
  @elseif ($award->color === 'EMERALD')
     bg-success text-white
  @else
     bg-white text-dark
  @endif">
     {{ $award->color }}
@endforeach

</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest ternary by using parenthesis also on blade like

```
<html>
{{$firstQuestion ? (secondQuestion ? $isTrue ? $isFalse) : ($doAnother ? $isTrue : $isFalse}}
</html>
```

But i don't recommend things like this. This is nasty to read and no straight forward
Ternary expression.
Ternary expressions are not made to simplify `elseif` statements.
Also the blade pattern should be:

````
<td 
  rowspan="{{count($awards)+1}}" 
  class= @if ($awards === 'DIAMOND')
             "bg-white text-dark"
          @elseif ($awards === 'RUBY')
             "bg-danger text-white"
          @elseif ($awards === 'EMERALD')
             "bg-success text-white"
          @else
             "bg-white text-dark"
          @endif>
             {{$award}}
</td>```
````